# I realized half an hour ago that it ____ time to go to my home country

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> **I realized** half an hour ago that **it was time** to go to my home country.
>
> **I realized** half an hour ago that **it is time** to go to my home country.

If I say that I will do this trip next month, I can't say "it is time", only "it was time" because of Past Simple in the beginning. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are possible, by the usual backshifting rules.

The past tense "it was time" is the backshifted form.

The present tense "it is time" is valid, if it continues to be "time to go back" at the time of speaking.

Using "it is time" seems to me to express greater determination to return.  Using "it was time" expresses the simple fact, without as much emotion or determination.  But this is nuance at most (and perhaps just my imagination)

Comment: It's the old debate about whether to say "I told him my name was Kate" or "is Kate" (it was then and still is).